# How to get the geolocation of an IP address in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, network

Is it possible to get the geolocation of an IP address in Terminal?

Not sure what the numbers in an IP address mean, but there must be some logic behind it, so lookup can't be that hard.

Comment: You want a geolocation of an Ip? https://www.iplocation.net/

Comment: Maybe with http://macappstore.org/geoip/

Comment: Or read this article: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100109053441706

Comment: Also in regard to your latter assertion, no there is no enforced correlation between public IP address values and geography. Companies and organisations lease blocks of IPs; they can do with them whatever they wish.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do this without having to install any additional apps or software.  Just use the command `curl` and the free geo ip website http://freegeoip.app.

Execute the following command in Terminal (I am using Apple's IP for this example):

`curl https://freegeoip.app/xml/17.178.96.59`

You will get your results in an XML format:

```
<Response>
    <IP>17.178.96.59</IP>
    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
    <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
    <RegionCode>CA</RegionCode>
    <RegionName>California</RegionName>
    <City>Cupertino</City>
    <ZipCode>95014</ZipCode>
    <TimeZone>America/Los_Angeles</TimeZone>
    <Latitude>37.3042</Latitude>
    <Longitude>-122.0946</Longitude>
    <MetroCode>807</MetroCode>
</Response>
```

You can even issue the same command using the domain name instead of the IP:

`curl https://freegeoip.app/xml/apple.com`

**Other Formats...**

freegeoip.app also supports CSV, JSON and JSONP

CSV:
`curl https://freegeoip.app/csv/apple.com`

```
17.178.96.59,US,United States,CA,California,Cupertino,95014,America/Los_Angeles,37.30,-122.09,807
```

JSON:  `curl https://freegeoip.app/json/apple.com`

```
{"ip":"17.178.96.59","country_code":"US","country_name":"United States","region_code":"CA","region_name":"California","city":"Cupertino","zip_code":"95014","time_zone":"America/Los_Angeles","latitude":37.3042,"longitude":-122.0946,"metro_code":807}
```

**To check your own ip...**

Just omit the ip or domain:

`curl https://freegeoip.app/xml/`

Comment: NOTE: linking an IP address to a geographical location is not a hard science. While most addresses will be reliable, there are millions of addresses that, when looked up, will resolve to a general location, like the center of a city, or even the middle of the country. There is an interesting article about how an random farm in the middle of Kansas has been the target of abuse and criminal investigations because a major geolocation service placed their "general location for the USA" flag on their farm. http://fusion.net/story/287592/internet-mapping-glitch-kansas-farm/ is a link to the article.

Comment: This API endpoint is deprecated and will stop working on July 1st, 2018. For more information please visit: https://github.com/apilayer/freegeoip#readme</DeprecationMessage>

Comment: looks like the new "freegeoip.app" works as expected. "freegeoip.net" was deprecated

Comment: @Allan `curl https://freegeoip.app/xml/` does not show IPv4

Comment: @SebMa -  Just tested it.  Works as described.

Comment: @Allan Do you obtain your public IPv4 or IPv6 ?

Comment: @SebMa IPv4 - It will report back what your ISP gives you but it works - it reports your *IP address*.

Comment: @Allan Actually https://freegeoip.app/xml/ reports my IPv6, but on the other hand https://ipinfo.io/json reports my IPv4. How come this has anything to do with my ISP ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a small and compact command line tool called gip, written in C++, available at https://github.com/softhub-software-development/gip.

Examples:

```
# gip softhub.com
91.65.13.31 "Berlin, Berlin, Germany"

# gip 91.65.13.31
91.65.13.31 "Berlin, Berlin, Germany"

# gip -t google.com
91.65.13.254 "Berlin, Berlin, Germany"
145.254.3.66 "Eschborn, Hessen, Germany"
72.14.194.138 "Mountain View, California, United States"

# gip -g softhub.com
52.5244 13.4105
```

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/maxmind/mmdbinspect with databases from https://github.com/wp-statistics/GeoLite2-City:

```
mmdbinspect -db "$database_file" "$ip"
```

You can use `jq` to further process the output.